# OutlinedInput labelWidth in percentage @material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Here is my component

```
<OutlinedInput
    labelWidth={'80%'}
    multiline={true}
    fullWidth={false}
    rows={5}
    rowsMax={7}
    value={this.state.Comments}
    onChange={this.handleCommentChange}
    style={{
        marginTop: '20px'
    }} />
```

As you can see I want to provide **labelWidth** in percentage but it expects number. Currently I am providing string and getting error saying that I have to provide number. Is there any easy way around or I have to calculate it using container width and give it to labelWidth as number?

Comment: Did you understand the concept of type checking with prop-types? If it is not working, it is simply not supported. You shouldn't look for a way around the type checking, else there wouldn't be any sense for prop-types in react.

Comment: But if I calculate using width of it's container then provide value as a number then it works fine.